# How change this from UIWebView to WKWebView?

Tags: objective-c, wkwebview

I have tried with the 3 or 4 posts about this here but none use file path and I cannot get this working with WKWebView, it works with UIWebView, please can someone help me.
Yes, I am very new to this, I tried all day before posting here tonight, so easy to understand instructions would be great. Thanks.

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *contentWebView;
@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize contentWebView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"LockBackground" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL * fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
    NSURLRequest * myNSURLRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:fileURL];
    [contentWebView loadRequest:myNSURLRequest];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Where's your problem? `WKWebView` also has a `loadRequest:` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply changing

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *contentWebView;
```

to

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView *contentWebView;
```

should work.

---

If you intend to provide support for both iOS 7 and iOS 8, you'll have to declare two variables and add the following verification:

```
if ([WKWebView class]) {
    // do new webview stuff
}
else {
    // do old webview stuff
}
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple, I also had to import WebKit/WebKit.h but it works. Thanks.